# Unauthenticated software sources

Tags: apt, update-manager, authentication

My Lucid (10.04) installation recently started warning me that the updated packages were unauthenticated. For instance, if I open Update Manager and click the "Install Updates" button, it warns me that *You are about to install software that **can't be authenticated**! Doing this could allow a malicious individual to damage or take control of your system.*

I don't remember seeing this before. I guess it looks like I don't have the right keys to verify signatures.

---

**Update** with more information:

I get the warning for *all* packages, including apt and linux-image.

This is what's in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` (sans comments)

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security multiverse
```

---

**update 2:**

Whatever it was that was wrong, it is no longer wrong, so I won't be able to verify any suggested solutions.

Comment: What is listed in System > Administration > Software Sources > Other Software?

Comment: I updated the question with more information.

Comment: What does `sudo apt-key list` show? It should include the Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (437D05B5). Also try doing `apt-get update` again (a.k.a. “Check” in Update Manager) in case this was a transient error on a the mirror.

Comment: It includes the key. And I'm pretty sure I have updated several times. But now I did it again, and it has stopped complaining.

Comment: ... which suggests a transient network or proxy error, or that the particular mirror you were hitting was having a problem.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes when a network connection interrupts `apt-get update` (or the automatic daily package list refresh), the signature file will not get written, resulting in `apt` yelling about the lack of authentication. In most situations (assuming no improperly configured transparent caching system is between you and the Internet), a simple `sudo apt-get update` will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are you've added a PPA repository and haven't added the corresponding keys. The simplest way to do this is to disable all the PPAs and go through each and throw them at `add-apt-repository`. This will add it back to your sources but also

So if you see something like this:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/f-spot/f-spot-ppa/ubuntu lucid main
```

Run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:f-spot/f-spot-ppa
```

I think you can also throw the whole sourceline at it so this should be valid too:

```
sudo add-apt-repository deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/f-spot/f-spot-ppa/ubuntu lucid main
```

Rinse and repeat for all your non-standard software sources.

Comment: Nope, no PPA, only lucid and lucid-updates repositories. And I get this warning for core packages such as apt itself.